# how to deploy stanford coreNLP server to an online webservice e.g. Heroku?

Tags: java, heroku, stanford-nlp

I would like to deploy the Stanford CoreNLP server so that I can access it as an API from another app of mine. This is probably rather trivial but there are not many resources regarding this around. Being a rather new developer, and not one experienced in Java, could someone point me to how I could get started with deploying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps easiest is to use a pre-built Docker image, e.g., as defined in [the docker section of the server documentation](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html#docker):

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 --name coreNLP --rm -i -t motiz88/corenlp
```

With the docker image at https://hub.docker.com/r/motiz88/corenlp/